# How to convert string values into date format in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime, type-conversion

In MS SQL Server, there are functions like Cast, Parse and Convert, but I can't find similar functions in PostgreSQL.

This is  the table in string format

[image]

How can convert it to date time format in yyyy-mm-dd style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Postgres doesn't have an error-tolerant `to_date()` function.  You could write one:

```
create or replace function to_date_noerror (s text, fmt text)
returns date as
$$
begin
    return to_date(s, fmt);
exception
    when others then return null;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Then you could try out formats:

```
select coalesce(to_date_noerror(col, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                to_date_noerror(col, 'DD MMM YY'),
                to_date_noerror(col, 'MMM DD YYYY),
                . . .
               )
```

You can do a reasonable approximation using regular expressions:

```
select (case when col ~ '^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}$'
             then to_date(col, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
             when col ~ '^[0-9]{1,2} [A-Z]{3} [0-9]{4}$'
             then to_date(col, 'DD MMM YYYY')
             . . .
        end)
```

However, this approach could still return errors and it is quite difficult to generate a regular expression that matches dates 100% (think of the problem with leap years).

That said, the real solution is to fix your data model.  Do not store dates as strings.  Fix the data when it goes into the database, so you don't have to deal with bad data.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres does have `CAST`:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS

or the Postgres shortcut:

`select '2-Jan-20'::date;`

Also data type conversion functions:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html

For this conversation, `to_date()` and `to_timestamp()`.

As to your examples the simplest way, with one exception is to do:

```
select '2-Jan-20'::date;
    date    
------------
 2020-01-02

select 'Sunday, August 1, 2021'::date;
    date    
------------
 2021-08-01

 select 'January 7 2023'::date;
    date    
------------
 2023-01-07
```

The exception being:

```
select '25/1/2028 4.25PM'::date;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "25/1/2028 4.25PM"
LINE 1: select '25/1/2028 4.25PM'::date;
```

This fails because of the period in the time. Even if you change that:

```
select '25/1/2028 4:25PM'::date;
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "25/1/2028 4:25PM"
LINE 1: select '25/1/2028 4:25PM'::date;
               ^
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.

--The date style has month/day/ordering
 show datestyle;
 DateStyle 
-----------
 ISO, MDY

--Changing it to day/month/ordering solves that issue.
set datestyle = iso, dmy;
SET

select '25/1/2028 4:25PM'::date;
    date    
------------
 2028-01-25
```

The important thing to remember is that if are going to change the values from strings to date/timestamps they are not stored formatted. The formatting you will see returned in a query is going to be determined by your [DateStyle](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) setting.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Gordon Linoff that the best option is to clean the data.
and also thanks to @Adrian Klaver for encouraging me to check out [postgresql cast function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfN0m.png)

I used this---

```
select cast ('2-Jan-20' as date)
union
select cast ('2-Jan-2025' as date)
union
select cast ('January 2 2023' as date)
union
select cast ('Sunday, August 1, 2021' as timestamp)
union
select cast ('25/1/2028 4:25 PM' as timestamp);
```

the result is

[image]

though, can't understand how to do it from the Table directly.